# How to create an AWS IAM role with JSON formatted trust policy string from a variable

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I am trying to create an AWS IAM role, supplying the assume role trust policy from a JSON formatted string instead of a JSON file. More specifically, in `aws iam create-role` command, when I use the option `--assume-role-policy-document file://iam_role_trust_policy.json"`, the IAM role is created. However, when I try the option `--assume-role-policy-document $IAM_ROLE_TRUST_POLICY`, it fails with the following error:

`Unknown options: "2012-10-17",, "Statement":, [, {, "Effect":, "Allow",, "Principal":, {, "AWS":, "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/svc-tooling-user", },, "Action":, "sts:AssumeRole", }, ], }, "Version":`

The variable `$IAM_ROLE_TRUST_POLICY` contains the same JSON string as the file `iam_role_trust_policy.json` contains.

It can be reproduced in the following way:

```
$ IAM_ROLE_TRUST_POLICY=$(cat <<-END
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/svc-tooling-user"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
END
)

$ aws iam create-role \
    --role-name  myTestRole\
    --assume-role-policy-document $IAM_ROLE_TRUST_POLICY
```

Result:

```
Unknown options: "2012-10-17",, "Statement":, [, {, "Effect":, "Allow",, "Principal":, {, "AWS":, "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/svc-tooling-user", },, "Action":, "sts:AssumeRole", }, ], }, "Version":
```

The following, using the option `file://` just works fine:

```
$ aws iam create-role \
    --role-name  myTestRole\
    --assume-role-policy-document file://iam_role_trust_policy.json
```

I compared the contents of the variable `IAM_ROLE_TRUST_POLICY` and the file `iam_role_trust_policy.json`.  They are identical.

```
$ echo $IAM_ROLE_TRUST_POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/svc-tooling-user"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

$ cat iam_trust_policy.json 
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/svc-tooling-user"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

What could be the issue here and how can I fix this?

Note: In the code and output, I replaced the actual AWS account with `111111111111`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it as follows (add quotes):

```
aws iam create-role \
    --role-name  myTestRole\
    --assume-role-policy-document "${IAM_ROLE_TRUST_POLICY}"
```

Comment: @Rafiq No problem. Glad it worked out:-)